# Query entities from google app engine using android

Tags: java, android, database, web-services, google-app-engine

Ive tried a thousand things. As of right now the only way for me to query anything is to get the entire list and look through it that way! which takes way to much time. How can I query something in google app engine, for example pull only the entities that have > 100 votes for example.

Im following the tic-tac-toe example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java and https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities
In the example I just switched notes for quotes.

Heres my current code for example on how im getting the entities
this is an async task and its loading each one which takes to long

```
 protected CollectionResponseQuotes doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Quotesendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Quotesendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Quotesendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();
  try {


      quotes = endpoint.listquotes().execute();

       for (Quotes quote : quotes.getItems()) {

           if (quote.getVotes() > 3) {

           quoteList.add(quote);

            }  

 }
```

Here is the code that Google generated in the app engine for me when I created the endpoint. It looks like it will query somehow but I cant figure it out. They are two different projects.

```
@Api(name = "quotesendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "projectquotes.com", ownerName = "projectquotes.com", packagePath = ""))
public class quotesEndpoint {

/**
 * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
 * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
 *
 * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
 * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "listquotes")
public CollectionResponse<quotes> listquotes(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

    EntityManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<quotes> execute = null;

    try {
        mgr = getEntityManager();
        Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from quotes as quotes");
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        execute = (List<quotes>) query.getResultList();
        cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

        // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
        // for lazy fetch.
        for (quotes obj : execute)
            ;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<quotes> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
}

/**
 * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
 *
 * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
 * @return The entity with primary key id.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "getquotes")
public quotes getquotes(@Named("id") String id) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    quotes quotes = null;
    try {
        quotes = mgr.find(quotes.class, id);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return quotes;
}
```

Tried to user cursor but now sure how it works. Ive tried

```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Votes WHERE Votes >" + 250 , null);
  quotes = endpoint.listquotes().setCursor(cursor).execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to pass parameters to endpoint.listquotes()?
Specifically parameter "limit" to limit a number of results and parameter "cursor" to change selection criteria?

Comment: Thanks for the responce! Do you mean something like this? Could you show me an example of how cursor would work here. Ive tried this below

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Votes WHERE Votes >" + 250 , null);
                    

quotes = endpoint.listquotes().setCursor(cursor).execute();

Comment: I dont have a database defined because i didn't need one

Comment: Updated the end of my question for you